# Order Ruby Hash by Key then Values

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using group_by to return a hash that I would like to order by key first, and then order the values under that key.

Here's the code I've come up with so far. Everything works fine, except I can't figure out how to sort the values after they're grouped.

I have a method, 'pp_accounts_with_properties' which shows my intent and prints out everything in the correct order (thanks to the properties.sort_by! call)... But it seems like I should be able to accomplish this somehow in the 'accounts_with_properties' method.

```
class ProofList
  attr_reader :client

  def initialize(client)
    @client = client
  end

  def properties
    @client.properties.joins(invoices: [charges: [:charge_credits]])
                      .where(charge_credits: { approved: false }).uniq
  end

  def accounts_with_properties
    unsorted_accounts_with_properties.sort_by { |account, properties| account[:acct_number] }
  end

  def unsorted_accounts_with_properties
    properties.group_by { |property| property.account }
  end

  def pp_accounts_with_properties
    accounts_with_properties.each do |account, properties|
      puts account.name
      properties.sort_by! { |p| p[:name] }
      properties.each do |property|
        puts property.name
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you...

1. Talking about showing some kind of sorted *display* of the keys and values of the Hash, or
2. Actually rearranging the interal structure of the Hash in some way?  So that, for example, a call to myhash.keys always returns things in a certain order?

If 2, why? You're barking up the wrong tree.  Hashes are just associations of keys with values, and if you're doing *anything* where the order of the keys matters, (other than trying to make a pretty/readable display), you're going about *something* the wrong way.

Check out this article for a clearer explanation than mine: http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to/ruby-sort-hash

Comment: I am just sorting for display purposes.  But I have to do it in several places, so I figured if I could do that as I generate it, then I could avoid sorting it everytime I display the data...  But yeah, I see your point trying to use the order to do any operation which manipulates data.